# How to keep the only sentences containing certain letters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I'm trying to accomplish with this is to exclude every sentence that are not English sentences. So I figured to use the English alphabet to include only the English sentences in my output file.

So the code is pretty self explanatory. However, I'm stuck at producing the final output. `output` list contains multiple instance of the same sentences because I'm appending in the second loop. If I do append it outside the second loop, then my character comparing logic is useless.

How do I include only English sentences in the output file?

```
filename = "lorem.txt"

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

char_list = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
output = []

for line in content:
    for word in line.split():
        if not any(char in word for char in char_list):
            continue
        else:
            output.append(line)

for entry in output:
    print(entry)
```

and the lorem.txt is

```
1. Lorem ñ ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
3. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
4. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
5. Despliega la cartera de la prueba para los diagnósticos agudos COVID-19 soportando diagnósticos diferenciados entre las infecciones         SARS-CoV-2 y la gripe común.
6. ﻮﺘﺘﻋﺮﺿ ﺈﻨﺟﺍﺯﺎﺗ ﺎﻠﻄﺑ ﺎﻠﺣﺪﻴﺛ ﻞﻠﺨﻃﺭ ﺐﻔﻌﻟ ﻢﻗﺍﻮﻣﺓ ﺎﻠﻤﺿﺍﺩﺎﺗ ﺎﻠﺤﻳﻮﻳﺓ، ﻮﺑﺎﺘﺗ ﻊﻤﻠﻳﺎﺗ ﺯﺮﻋ ﺍﻸﻌﺿﺍﺀ ﻭﺎﻠﻋﻼﺟ ﺎﻠﻜﻴﻤﻳﺎﺌﻳ ﻭﺎﻠﻌﻤﻠﻳﺎﺗ ﺎﻠﺟﺭﺎﺤﻳﺓ، ﻢﺜﻟ ﻊﻤﻠﻳ        ﺎﺗ ﺎﻟﻭﻻﺩﺓ ﺎﻠﻘﻴﺻﺮﻳﺓ، ﺄﻜﺛﺭ
7. This is English sentence.
```

So basically, `2, 3, 4, 7` would be outputted because they ONLY contains English letters.

Comment: What's going wrong here, do you think?

Comment: You can't distinguish an English sentence by English alphabet because that is Latin alphabet in the first place, You need a dictionary for that since other languages use Latin alphabet at least as a base so it could happen that there is a sentence in another language that just happens to match all Latin letters.

Comment: If you add " " to your char_list, you can skip the split.  That eliminates the inner loop and basically solves your problem.

Comment: Well, I think they could get close. I'm not sure why `.` isn't being considered too, since it's on every line, both in enumeration and in ending sentences...

Comment: @roganjosh what do You mean close? 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 7th sentence would match so that in this case would be a 1 out of 4 match. I would suggest that it would be better to also try by finding the most common English words too like 'the', 'a' or whatever. So keep this character check but also check for common English words

Comment: @Matiiss `ñ` fails line 1, `ó` line 5, 6 is self-explanatory. They, I _suspect_, made a poor choice in phrasing it as "English" characters. In any case, the `.` breaks every single line except 6 because it's not in `char_list` (as I pointed out)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isascii()` method to check if all characters in the string are ASCII. `s.isascii()` returns `true` if all characters in `s` are roman characters (both uppercase and lowercase), or other ASCII (such as space, tab, etc., see http://www.asciitable.com/ for a list of characters included).

```
filename = "lorem.txt"

output = []

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    if line.isascii():
        output.append(line.strip())

print(output)
```

output:

```
['Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.', 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.', 'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'This is English sentence.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over every char in each line and use str.isalpha() to ignore characters that wouldn't be letters anyway. Then there should be no* issues with numbers or punctuation in your example.

Also you can `import string` for string.ascii_letters instead of hardcoding the alphabet.

```py
import string
char_list = string.ascii_letters

output = []

for line in content:
    skip = False
    for char in line:
        if char.isalpha() and char not in char_list:
            skip = True
            break
    if not skip:
        output.append(line) # output ends up with lines 2, 3, 4, and 7 from the example
```

* There could be issues with non-english numbers or punctuation but I don't know if there's a simple way to differentiate those. str.isnumeric() could filter out some non-English numbers like `十` (Chinese symbol for 10) but would also filter out `½` which I'd say is English. ‍♂️